# bootstrap form inside modal not aligned properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to make a modal form using bootstrap (horizontal form) and the field are shown under the labels. Any idea how can I fix it so the input text boxes will be at the right of the labels and not under them?

[image]

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close specialb" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <form class="form-horizontal" class="non-margined">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="firstName">First name:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="FirstName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="lastName">Last name:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password" id="lastName" placeholder="LastName" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password" id="emailAddress" placeholder="EmailAddress" />
                    </div>
                </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML and CSS

Comment: Its working fine  http://bootply.com/88453

Comment: yep I know, if I put the form in a page (no modal) is shown correct. if it's in modal then is broken ...

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your form in a row-fluid ? Maybe your modal-width is too low .... :-/

Answer (score 7):

You need to place the form-horizontal declaration in with the modal-body declaration. This works.

`<div class="modal-body form-horizontal">`

Answer (score 4):

I am using bootstrap v3.3.2. I was in a similar situation yesterday and this is what worked out for me.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="step2">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name" />
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email-Id</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email-Id" />                  
                  </div>
              </div>
```

[image: modal-horizontal-form]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/c8RCV/)**